# How to deploy google cloud function when main.py and requirements.txt aren't in the same directory

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I have a directory structure that looks like this:

```
src/
    main.py
requirements.txt
```

Since there doesn't seem to be [any configurability](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--entry-point) surrounding where to look for `requirements.txt`, I have been resigned to running `gcloud functions deploy` in the outer directory, and I was hoping that the `--entry-point` flag might give me some wiggle room to target `main.py` inside `src`. Unfortunately, it seems to only define a method name.

So is there any way to make this work aside from forcing `main.py` and `requirements.txt` to be in the same directory?

For reference, the command I'm trying to run and corresponding error message:

```
gcloud functions deploy refresh_classes --entry-point main --runtime python37 --trigger-resource send_refresh --trigger-event google.pubsub.topic.publish --timeout 540s

Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: File main.py that is expected to define function doesn't exist
```

Comment: Just curious, what are you trying to avoid with the "recommended" directory structure? Or what's the reason your project needs to be structured in this way?

Comment: Also, the [`--source`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/deploy#--source) option allows you to change the source directory from the default (current directory) but it still expects the `main.py` and `requirements.txt` file to both be in that directory.

Comment: @DustinIngram to be honest I'm just new to cloud functions and didn't know there was a recommended directory structure

Comment: also, I have a config file that's being referenced in `main.py`, is that not allowed in cloud functions either? @DustinIngram

Comment: You can add as many additional files as you want. The only requirement is a `main.py` file, and a `requirements.txt` file if you want to install dependencies, in the same directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible by configuring `gcloud` alone, or without additional source files. Cloud Functions expects a single `source` directory which contains both a `requirements.txt` and `main.py`.